# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ), then =>, then {

Tags: node.js

Any idea what the issue is with my code?

Here is my code:

```
var server = app.listen(port, () => {
console.log('Server live on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? The "fat arrow" function syntax is a recent addition.

Comment: You need to update your Node; you have an outdated version.

Comment: Thanks! Yeh that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is ecmascript6 which is only in new versions of node

Older versions only have ecmascript 5 available

Only use es6 if u don't need to support older node versions unless u want a Babel dependency